# I am getting an error while extracting data

Tags: python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com.tr/s?me=A2OCQ69K09P55W&marketplaceID=A33AVAJ2PDY3EV")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html")

urunler = soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"sg-col-inner"} )


for urun in urunler:
    urun_linkleri= urun.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"aok-relative"})
    for i in urun_linkleri:
        link = i.find("span",attrs={"class":"rush-component"})
        link_devam = link.a.get("href")
        link_basi = "https://www.amazon.com.tr/"
        link_tamami=link_basi+link_devam
        print(link_devam)
```

after writing these codes it gives this output

```
/Genel-VA%C4%B0LLANT-VUW-AKI%C5%9E-T%C3%9CRB%C4%B0N%C4%B0/dp/B0B7K6P3BS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[39], line 5
      3 for i in urun_linkleri:
      4     link = i.find("span",attrs={"class":"rush-component"})
----> 5     link_devam = link.a.get("href")
      6     link_basi = "https://www.amazon.com.tr/"
      7     link_tamami=link_basi+link_devam

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I haven't tried anything. but I want to get the link of all the products in the rush-component class under the span that should be.

Comment: The link variable must be null/None. What does the HTML look like? Is the element there?

Answer (score 0):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'

This is because you try to access the `"href"` attribute on a `NoneType` object (the anchor tag `<a>` was not found), and it raises the `AttributeError`. Some of the elements in the `urun_linkleri` list might not have an anchor tag under the `<span class="rush-component">`

To avoid this error, you can add a check to see if the `link` variable and `link.a` are not `None` before trying to access the `"href"` attribute.

```py
...
for urun in urunler:
    urun_linkleri = urun.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "aok-relative"})
    for i in urun_linkleri:
        link = i.find("span", attrs={"class": "rush-component"})
        if link is not None and link.a is not None:
            link_devam = link.a.get("href")
            link_basi = "https://www.amazon.com.tr/"
            link_tamami = link_basi + link_devam
            print(link_tamami)
```

Comment: Thanks but now  it extracts 3 5 from a link

Comment: ok im solved the problem